# Create new records within a model method definition

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, api, model, rails-activerecord

In the controller I am trying to find contacts via the `find_contacts` method and set those contacts to an instance variable. I am using a module that queries an API that returns an array of JSON data. I would like to use that JSON data to create new records in the database, and then return all those created records to the controller. My attempt

```
def find_contacts(params)
  found_contacts = API.query(params[:name], params[:job])
  # found_contacts array of json data [{data}, {data}]

  contacts = found_contacts.reduce([]) do |contacts, contact|
    contacts << Contact.create(contact)
  end
  return contacts
end
```

Is this a valid way of creating and returning the records?

Comment: Simplification: `contacts = found_contacts.map { |json| Contact.create(json) }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use

```
contacts = Contact.create found_contacts
```